# Validation rule correction

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I am working on a validation rule where Current user cannot be Record creator /Con Owner.
Here I am storing current user in a field called requester and it should no be same as either the record(referring to the object gc in which I am creating the validation) creator or the con owner. Here in gc I have given con as a master detail field.

My validation rule:

```
OR (Requester__c = Con__r.OwnerId,
Requester__c= $User.Id)
```

Gave record creator as $User.Id

Is it the right way?

Comment: For creator you have to check with  `CreatedBy.Id`  or `Createdbyid`. `$User.Id` will give you the current user id who is editing it

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Actually that is fixed instead of user id I gave requested by id which was the needed condition. So new formula is OR (Requester__c = Con__r.OwnerId,
Requester__c= $Requested_by.Id).

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I have to add an extra condition such that if the requested by or requester field is null then the validation shouldnt occur. How it is possible.

Comment: As you said that the validation should not fire for Requester__c is null you have to add AND condition for it as below.  `AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Requester__c)),NOT(ISBLANK(Requested_by__c)), OR (Requester__c = Con__r.OwnerId, Requester__c= $Requested_by.Id) )`

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Thanks it worked.

Comment: I will answer the same here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creator you have to check with `CreatedBy.Id` or `Createdbyid`.

`$User.Id` will give you the current user id who is editing it .

And also as mentioned in my comment if you want to bypass this validation rule if  Requester__c is blank then you have to use `AND()` condition. So your validation rule will be as below.

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Requester__c)),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Requested_by__c)), 
    OR (Requester__c = Con__r.OwnerId, 
        Requester__c= $Requested_by.Id) )
```